# How to insert date in a table column with a trigger. (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sqlplus

Essentially I wish to create a trigger that keeps track and edits the `date_created` column of a specific row after every insert or update.

These are the columns in my table:

```
| customer_id | store_id | Quantity | date_created |
```

the customer_id and store_id together are the primary key of the table

What I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_trig
BEFORE INSERT ON customer_table
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
BEGIN

-- This is where I assume the date will be set or edited

END;
```

I am brand new to PL/SQL so I am struggling with the actual body of this trigger.

Also, do I have the structure of a trigger correctly formed?

Comment: You do not need to do this.  You can define a `date_created` with a default value of `sysdate`.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but I do need to use a trigger for this in my case.

Comment: If you struggle with the basics please take a look e.g. [PL/SQL Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) from the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please find sample code.

```
create or replace trigger emp_mod_date
before update or insert on emp
for each row
begin
 :new.mdate := sysdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `DEFAULT SYSDATE` on the colum `date_created` like already suggested
2. if you insist to use a trigger, just write `:NEW.date_created := SYSDATE;`

Comment: Yes I want to teach myself some PL/SQL so I need to write a trigger for this. Is that really all I need to put into the body of the trigger for the create date to work?

Comment: Try adding `/` after your `END;` in the next line which is the standard termination delimiter when creating a PL/SQL program unit, a trigger and so on.

Comment: Thanks olli that worked. But the date_created column is empty so I assume the trigger doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the Trigger was created correctly? Issue a `SHOW ERROR` right  after the trigger creation. I missed a `:` in my answer - I edited it. Please check and retry.

Comment: I added the edit but the date created columns are still all empty.